# Apps with 2 admob accounts on 1 developer account

Tags: android, admob

I have 1 developer account, and about 10 apps, all of which use **my admob** account.

I am creating a new app with a friend and I plan to use **his admob** ads for this app.

Can this be done? Do I risk both accounts by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, there is no such restrict that you can only use your own ADMOB account for your applications.

Comment: Thanks alot Robin. I couldn't see such restriction on admob documentation but still google is very strict and I needed to make sure.